# Ebean fail to insert a item in a list

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I have juste updated to play framework 2.4 but it seems that Ebean have change his behavior.

Here is my problem :

```
public static CommitItem create(String epc, PairingCommit commit)
{
    commit.refresh();
    CommitItem item = new CommitItem();
    item.epc = epc;
    commit.items.add(item);
    commit.update();
    return item;
}
```

Give the error :

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[update commit_item set evat_price=?, ivat_price=?, vat=?, discount=?, discount_is_percentage=?, product_product_code=? where epc=?] bind[null]
```

This error is raised because Ebean wants to update `commit_item` instead of insert a new item.

I have tried to change `update()` by `save()`but it gives the same error.

It was working before updating to new version.

---

**PairingCommit.java**

```
@Entity
public class PairingCommit extends Model
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    /** Other attributes **/

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CommitItem> items;
}
```

**CommitItem.java**

```
@Entity
public class CommitItem extends Model
{
    @Id
    public String epc;

    /** Other attributes **/
}
```

Comment: Try to save `item` before adding it to `commit.items`

Comment: It's bit working because of unidirectional relationship. And this code was working well before update. It should work like this